# Keynote equation: is it possible to predefine LaTeX macros?

Tags: keynote

Is it possible to add to the LaTeX preamble for the Keynote equation tool? For example, the default setting is that \vec{x} generates an arrow over the letter `x`, but I would like this to produce a bold `x`.

Comment: Might be useful - https://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/Keynote.html & this - https://support.apple.com/kb/PH26902?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US.